# How can I temporarily disable all (other) key bindings?

Tags: key-bindings, eshell, commands

How can I write a command, and bind it to a key, so that when invoked it disables all key bindings other than the current key, until that same key binding is pressed again?

The goal is to facilitate easier interaction with terminal interfaces when in vterm, eshell, etc.

Comment: You won't be able to interact with anything at all if you've disabled all key bindings.  Literally the only thing you'd be able to do is toggle your feature off again with the one single key binding that still worked.  (If typing a key does *anything at all* in Emacs, it's because there's a key binding for it.)

Comment: Ah. Might have been unclear. I'm basically trying to get all keys passed through to vterm.

Comment: vterm and eshell are *so* different that I suggest you narrow the scope of your question to only one of them.  You could always ask a separate question about the other.